# How to write and read bits one by one in a file via NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stream, binary, buffer, machine-code

I want to create a  binary file using `0` and `1` bit values and then I want to read them one by one.

How can I do this?

For writing I tried:

```
var out = require("fs").createWriteStream("./out");
out.write(new Buffer("0"));   // this writes "0" as string
out.write(new Buffer(["0"])); // this creates something strange,
                              // but I'm not sure it's the needed thing
```

After the file exists, I want to iterate all bits from that file:

```
require("fs").readFile("./out", function (err, buff) {
   // how to access here `0` and `1` values?
});
```

What's the proper way for doing this?

Comment: Can you expound a bit?  What specifically are you trying to do?  It would be possible to create a transform stream, if a stream is indeed what you want, but that isn't clear.  Otherwise, you will have to read/write byte values and use a bit mask to get the values you want.

Comment: @Brad From what I saw on other posts reading by bytes can be implemented using `stream.on("byte", ...)` and that's what I need actually. I'm writing an assembler and an interpreter apps for ARC machine. For that I need to store byes (32 bits) in a binary file, and then to interpret them, but first I need to write them properly, read them properly and handle them, finally.

Comment: Do you want bytes or 32-bit integers?  The buffer class lets you read/write all sorts of values, to and from buffers.

Comment: @Brad My bad, *1 byte === 8 bits*, I need to write and read successions of 32 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffers operate at the byte level. Once you access a particular byte (e.g. `buff[0]`), it's just a normal javascript number, so you can you do whatever bit operations on that number (e.g. `buff[0] & 0x0F`).

There are [convenience functions](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html) on Buffer objects that allow you to write different kinds of numbers too. For example: `buff.writeUInt32BE(5, 0)` will write a 32-bit unsigned integer 5 in big endian mode at position 0 in the Buffer. To read a 32-bit unsigned integer in big endian mode at position 0: `buff.readUInt32BE(0)`.

Comment: So having the following string: "11000010000000000010100000010100" how can I write (and then read) it into (from) a file in binary format? Should I do `new Buffer(str.split("").map(function (c) { return parseInt(c); }))`?

Comment: That's a 32-bit integer, so the simplest way might be: `var buf = new Buffer(4); buf.writeUInt32BE(parseInt(str, 2), 0);`. Then use `buf` wherever. To write just that number to a file, you might do something like: `fs.writeFileSync('foo.dat', buf);`

Comment: I think the missing piece here is `parseInt(stringOfOnesAndZeroes, 2)` -- you can turn a "binary string" into an actual number using base-2 parseInt.